# Change while loops based on intervals defined by vector

Tags: matlab, logic

Inside my code I currently have 2 while loops looking like this:

```
sequence = [15 35 50];

startStamp = GetSecs %GetSecs is a psychtoolbox function that returns the current time in seconds

while GetSecs - startStamp < sequence(1) || (GetSecs - startStamp >= sequence(2) && GetSecs - startStamp <= sequence(3))
cond1 %display stimulus 1
end

while GetSecs - startStamp >= sequence(1) && GetSecs - startStamp < sequence(2)
cond2 %display stimulus 2
end
```

Whenever the timer (GetSecs - startStamp) reaches one of the elements of sequence I want to go from one while loop into the other and then execute it until the next element of sequence is reached, switch loops and so forth...

The way I structured my conditional statements for entering the while loops is not very slim but it becomes exponentially worse as numel(sequence) increases.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly and to work with a variable length of seqeunce?

Comment: Make a single while loop that contains conditional evaluations and a big switch case is an option

Comment: What do you mean by big switch case?

Comment: do you need to use absolute time values or can you simply use `pause(1)` to time your stimuli? In that case the code becomes trivial: `for ind=1:5, disp('stim1'); pause(1); end;` and so forth

Comment: @Noah069 a "switch case" is one of the fundamental structures of programming languages, have a look online ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable length of array sequence, you can use one big while loop for looping through elements of the sequence array, and place flag inside the loop that will tell you which condition to use.

Translated to code:

```
counter = 1; flag = true;
while(counter <= length(sequence))
    while(GetSecs - startStamp < sequence(counter))
        if flag
            cond1;
        else
            cond2;
        end
    end

    flag = ~flag;
    counter = counter + 1 ;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sequence = [15 35 50];

startStamp = GetSecs %GetSecs is a psychtoolbox function that returns the current time in seconds

while (Getsecs - startStamp) < sequence(end)

    for i=1:length(sequence)
        if (Getsecs-startStamp) < sequence(i)
            break
        end
    end

    if mod(i,2) == 1
        cond1       

    else
        cond2 
    end

end
```